# How to render a Twig template without passing any array to render() method?

Tags: php, arrays, twig, template-engine

I am using Twig a few days, and it's very nice, but now I am in a situation where I need to render a template without passing any array to the render() method.

I am using:

```
echo $template->render();
```

but Twig raises an exception because I NEED to pass some array to the render. So I tried:

```
echo $template->render(array(''=>''));
```

and it works, but it's so ugly.

Any tips about this? Thanks!

Comment: `echo $template->render(array());` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing an array that contains an empty string element, you should also be able to pass the template an empty array:

```
echo $template->render(array());
```

Apart from that, you are probably using Twig this way:

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html.twig');
echo $template->render(array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

[The Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html) suggests an easier way to do the same:

```
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

The additional benefit is that the `render` method of the `Twig_Environment` class allows you to omit the second argument (it defaults to an empty array), so now you can simply do this:

```
echo $twig->render('index.twig.html');
```